# PostgreSQL - Any way I can define a column that will cast empty string to null on insert or update?

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, casting

I am using PostgreSQL 12. I have **'users'** table where **'email'** column is nullable means optional column, however it has unique constraint as expected. This 'email' column is **'citext'** type column.

The problem is even I send 'email' value as **NULL**, the database saves it as empty string instead NULL in 'email' column during insert. Is there any way I can cast empty string to NULL for 'email' column on insert or update? Because it has unique constraint and it needs to be NULL if multiple users did not provide 'email' to avoid unique constraint error.

I am using PHP Laravel framework. There is no mutator defined. The controller part is following:

```
    var_dump($user->email); // email is null still

    $success = $user->save(); // save DB changes by ORM

    var_dump($user->email); // is '' string now, NULL expected
```

I expect the casting should happens in background or by PostgreSQL itself automatically during insert or update. May be something like 'CHECK' constraint there we can define in column that will cast automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The database is not converting `NULL` to an empty string, this is being done on the client side. You will need to provide more information about what your client is and how you creating and sending the query to the database.

Comment: You can have a trigger that performs the conversion. (And checks for @ etc.)

Comment: Then it is something being done in whatever `$user` represents. I am not a `PHP` programmer so someone else will have to chime in on this.

Comment: You will need a trigger to simulate Oracle's behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as @a_horse_with_no_name noted, a check constraint will not help. Here is a trigger definition that should fix your case.

```sql
create or replace function emailfix_tf()
returns trigger language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  new.email := nullif(trim(new.email), '');
  return new;
end;
$$;

create trigger users_emailfix_t
before insert or update on users
for each row execute procedure emailfix_tf();
```

Anyway it's a pity that you have to define a trigger in order to fix data that has been malformed and spoiled by your ORM.

Answer (score 4):

You could use  NULLIF()

```
INSERT INTO your_table (cols..., email) VALUES (..., NULLIF(your_email, ''))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any constraint like 'CHECK()' we can alter and change column definition? So PostgreSQL automatically casts it?

Comment: PostgreSQL don't cast automatically an empty string in null as oracle .. if you need  this you can use a trigger or manage te conversion in Insert or Update phase...anyway the function is NULLIF()